# MongoDB - SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: mongodb

Am trying to run this simple query and am getting

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

```
db.Bookdetail.insert({
      "Subject":"Book Details",
      "Details": [
        {
          "Book Id"："001",
          "Book Name"："C# step by step",
          "Book Description"："Programming book on C#"
        },
        {
          "Book Id"："002",
          "Book Name"："Head First Java",
          "Book Description"："Programming Book on Java"
        }, 
        {
          "Book Id"："003",
          "Book Name"："Steve Jobs",
          "Book Description"："biography of Jobs"
        }
      ]
    });
```

Comment: it seems you copied the query from invalid source, the colon character is not proper.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the `:` in `"Book Id"："001"` is invalid. Per your code, the `：`in `"Book Id"："001"` is full width letter, which is invalid character for JS

Comment: Hi it's not invalid. I have entered the same format many times. There is some other minor issue. cannot find it.

Comment: @Bramenath, per the code posted in your question the `:` of `"Book Id"："001"` is different with the `:` of `"Subject":"Book Details"` obviously. please check it again.

Answer (score 0):

please use this code.

```
db.Bookdetail.insert({
      "Subject":"Book Details",
      "Details": [
        {
          "Book Id":"001",
          "Book Name":"C# step by step",
          "Book Description":"Programming book on C#"
        },
        {
          "Book Id":"002",
          "Book Name":"Head First Java",
          "Book Description":"Programming Book on Java"
        }, 
        {
          "Book Id":"003",
          "Book Name":"Steve Jobs",
          "Book Description":"biography of Jobs"
        }
      ]
    });
```

It seems you copied query form the source, it has invalid character.

Thanks

Comment: @Bramenath please mark the answers and correct mark so that community can follow the right answers straight away.